# Can local actions have multiple parents?

Tags: 7, routes

I have a module that I am working on that defines some local tasks and local actions for node pages, eg

```
$items['node/%node/foo'] = array(
  'title' => 'Foo',
  'page callback' => 'foo',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

$items['node/%node/bar'] = array(
  'title' => 'Bar',
  'page callback' => 'bar',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
);
```

This works mostly great.  'Foo' appears as a new tab on node pages, and 'Bar' shows up as a local action on the 'node/%node' page.

I would like my 'node/%node/bar' local action to also show up on the 'node/%node/foo' page as a local action.  Is this possible?  I have tried playing with the 'tab_parent' and 'tab_root' parameters, but this only seems to work with local tasks and it also doesn't seem to allow multiple parents.

Comment: I am not sure about this but you may be able to do it by implementing `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter` and alter the `$data['actions']['output'];`. In any case, I feel like you are trying to convert a sibling relations ship between the menu items into a parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's always Many (Local Actions) to one (Parent Item) relationship as hook_menu documentation says

> MENU_LOCAL_ACTION: Local actions are menu items that describe actions
>   on the **parent item** such as adding a new user or block, and are
>   rendered in the action-links list in your theme.

If you want to change the parent of local action you can do it using tab_parent

```
  $items['node/%node/bar'] = array(
      'title' => 'Bar',
      'page callback' => 'bar',
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'tab_parent' => 'node/%/foo',
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
  );
```

Above displays action link in node/%/foo instead of node/% , tab_parent accepts single string argument... So we can rule out option of sending multiple parents using array.. For deeper analysis you can refer

function menu_local_tasks() in menu.inc which is responsible for action items and local tasks rendering..

If you would like to see it in action both places you can try below..

As @awm pointed out in comment we can add it to other pages using hook_menu_local_tasks_alter, Here is how node module does to include node/add menu item as local action to admin/content using hook_menu_local_tasks_alter

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function node_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  // Add action link to 'node/add' on 'admin/content' page.
  if ($root_path == 'admin/content') {
    $item = menu_get_item('node/add');
    if ($item['access']) {
      $data['actions']['output'][] = array(
        '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
        '#link' => $item,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

So you can do same for your own implementation using below code

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  // Add action link to 'node/add' on 'admin/content' page.
  if ($root_path == 'node/%/foo') {
    $nid = arg(1);
    $item = menu_get_item('node/'. $nid . '/bar');
    if ($item['access']) {
      $data['actions']['output'][] = array(
          '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
          '#link' => $item,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Results in

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the example.  Didn't notice that when I was searching.